# How to make mysql connection that requires CA-CERT with sqlalchemy or SQLObject

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sqlobject

I would like to connect to a MySQL database that requires ca-cert.  I can do it with MySQLdb like below:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host,
                port = self.port,
                unix_socket = self.unix_socket,
                user = self.user,                                
                passwd = self.passwd,
                db = self.db,
                ssl = { 'cert': self.sslcert,
                        'key': self.sslkey,
                         'ca': self.sslca }
```

How do I do the same think in SQLAlchemy or SQLObject?

Thanks,
peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[create_engine() in SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) has a `connect_args` parameter:

> `connect_args` – a dictionary of options which will be passed directly
>   to the DBAPI’s `connect()` method as additional keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link.  The documentation doesn't seem to have examples of what those options are?  Are they identical to the MySQLdb library?

Comment: They are passed directly to DB API's `connect()`, i.e. `MySQLdb.connect()` in your case.

Comment: got it, so it's identical.  Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

To use SSL certs with SQLAlchemy and MySQLdb, use the following python code:

```
db_connect_string='mysql://<user>:<pswd>@<db server>:3306/<database>'
ssl_args = {'ssl': {'cert':'/path/to/client-cert', 
                     'key':'/path/to/client-key', 
                      'ca':'/path/to/ca-cert'}}

create_engine(db_connect_string, connect_args=ssl_args)
```

Comment: With the latest versions, it should be 
                    ```ssl_args = {'ssl_cert':'/path/to/client-cert', 
                     'ssl_key':'/path/to/client-key', 
                      'ssl_ca':'/path/to/ca-cert'}```

Comment: With the latest version, make sure your ssl_args is in this format `ssl_args = {'sslrootcert':'server-ca.pem',
            'sslcert':'client-cert.pem',
            'sslkey':'client-key.pem'}`

Comment: The approach noted in this answer appears to be correct if you're using PyMySQL

Answer (score 1):

SQLObject (untested):

```
from sqlobject.mysql import MySQLConnection
connection = MySQLConnection(
    db=self.db,
    user=self.user,
    password=self.password,
    host=self.host,
    ssl_key=self.sslkey,
    ssl_cert=self.sslcert,
    ssl_ca=self.sslca,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine), SQLAlchemy's `create_engine` function takes a db url with the following format: `dialect[+driver]://user:password@host/dbname[?key=value..]` meaning you could pass the ssl key, cert, and ca as key value pairs.

Comment: Yes, I want this. But what are the key names? if I try 'sslca' I get an exception `TypeError: 'sslca' is an invalid keyword argument for connect()`

Comment: I would assume the keys are dialect specific and would be found in their corresponding docs. I know that for mysql, you have to a pass a `--ssl-ca` arg though the command line to connect using SSL; Maybe try `ssl-ca=foo` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't find anything in docs. I tried all kinds of variations ('ssl-ca', 'ssl.ca', 'ssl_ca', 'sslca', 'ssl', 'ca', etc.). Since I am using Django, I ended up passing this parameter in Django setup. Hack, but works.