# How to connect to mysql server with SSL from a flask app

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to connect to a mysql server via flask and

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://your-username:your-password@localhost/schema'
```

How can I add ca-cert, client-key and client-cert to the connection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add theses informations in your URI like this :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://your-username:your-password@localhost/schema?ssl_key=MyCertFolder/client-key.pem&ssl_cert=MyCertFolder/client-cert.pem'
```

Or using the SQLAlchemy create_engine, take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014781/how-to-make-mysql-connection-that-requires-ca-cert-with-sqlalchemy-or-sqlobject)

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to use a Cloud-based MySQL service, this configuration will be slightly different. For example,

In Azure, it will be,

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://your-username:your-password@localhost/your-schema?ssl_ca=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'
```

wherein, the file BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem can be downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl).

Similarly, the solution for AWS is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372772/flask-sqlalchemy-ssl-connection-with-aws-rds-error).

Comment: In my case working option was `?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL to define the URL.

```
sqlUrl = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    drivername="mysql+pymysql",
    username=db_user,
    password=db_pass,
    host=db_host,
    port=3306,
    database=db_name,
    query={"ssl_ca": "main_app/certs/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem"},
)
create_engine(sqlUrl)
```

You can include SSL parameters as a dictionary in the query argument.

This approach is useful if you are using Flask to initialize the SqlAlchemy engine with a config parameter like SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI rather than directly using create_engine.