# Flask-SQLAlchemy ssl-connection with AWS RDS error

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect flask app mysql connection with AWS RDS over ssl , It works when I am try to use mysql client like this

`mysql -u user -h myrds.rds.amazonaws.com -p --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

I am able to login but when I am try with flask app

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:Password@myrds.rds.amazonaws.com.rds.amazonaws.com/miro_dev?ssl_cert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'`

it send me error

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2026, 'SSL connection error: Unable to get private key')`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this work by adding

`?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

to the connection string.

This came from the postgresql docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) along with the [aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL).

You can change the sslmode to require if you do not care about verifying the rds. I downloaded the pem file from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem).

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your case the connection string is correct, you just need to use `ssl_ca` option and not `ssl_cert`:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:password@myrds.rds.amazonaws.com.rds.amazonaws.com/miro_dev?ssl_ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
...
ssl_args = {'ssl': {'ca': 'YOUR_SSL_CERT_PATH'}}

db_url = 'mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(username, password, server, database)
engine = create_engine(db_url, connect_args=ssl_args, echo=False)
cnx = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql_table('table_name', cnx)
```

And I'd suggest to not input a path like follows:

~/...

but:

/home/YOUR_USER/...