# How to use Alembic with a SSL connection?

Tags: ssl, alembic

I use Alembic to manage my migrations. My database is on AWS, and I want to connect it with SSL.

In my `alembic.ini` I have the lines

```
[production]
script_location = alembic_prod
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://user:password@my-rds-host.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/mydatabase
```

Of course, it works if `user` have the permission to connect the base without SSL, but not otherwise.

How to require a SSL connection, and specify the [certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need the certificate bundle -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

You then would add the appropriate parameter to your URL like shown here -

[How to connect to mysql server with SSL from a flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785252/how-to-connect-to-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-a-flask-app)

Comment: I had 2 problems : 
First it can't be done with old versions of python, because SSLContext was introduced in 2.7.9
And finally, with RDS, it works with the `ssl_ca` option in the url, which is not mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the previous answer with more specific steps:

1. Download the RDS certificate bundle from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem
2. Use the `ssl_key` option to point to the certificate:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://user:password@my-rds-host.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/mydatabase?ssl_key=/Users/DaMaill/Downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem
```