# Use Alembic on GitLab to update AWS RDS instance

Tags: gitlab, amazon-rds, gitlab-ci, alembic

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab to use Alembic to automatically upgrade a Postgres instance running on AWS RDS. I am using GitLab's hosted vcs rather than having it installed on-prem, so I am unable to specifically whitelist the runner's IP in AWS.

I have been looking through [How to use Alembic with a SSL connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317055/how-to-use-alembic-with-a-ssl-connection) to try and connect using SSL, but am unsure how to get this working in GitLab. I'd prefer not to check the certificate files into my repo, but also can't think of another way around it using the hosted GitLab.

my .gitlab-ci.yml is pretty simple otherwise:

```
test:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - alembic upgrade head
```

Has anyone had experience trying to deploy schema updates to AWS RDS using GitLab's CI/CD?