# Is it possible to pass a dictionary into create_engine function in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to start a connection to an Azure SQL database. For security reasons I cannot hardcode in the username and password, I need to get it from a dictionary in a config file and put it into the connection URL that way.

When I try to do so and run it in a Jupyter notebook, the `{key[value]}` is not being replaced by what it refers to in the config file.

If I use a formatted string, I get a `KeyError`. If I do not use a formatted string, it simply prints the `{variablename}` literally.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot pass a dictionary straight into `create_engine()` as a substitute for the url, however you can pass a [`sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/a3145cffe2bdce393795cf9cd51605227be00b7f/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py#L26) object which can be instantiated easily with a `dict`.

From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html?#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL):

> This object is suitable to be passed directly to a create_engine()
> call.

For example:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

config = dict(
    drivername='driver',
    username='username',
    password='qwerty1',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port='5000',
    database='mydb',
    query={'encoding': 'utf-8'}
)

url = URL.create(**config)

print(url)  # driver://username:qwerty1@127.0.0.1:5000/mydb?encoding=utf-8

engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
```

However, the issues you are having with passing in a string formatted URL aren't likely to be a SQLAlchemy problem as the string formatting would take place before `create_engine()` gets it's hands on the string. Unfortunately your question doesn't include an example that reproduces the exact problem you are having, so I cannot say much more than that.

Comment: Can that config dict include SSL credentials?

Comment: SSL args can be passed as a `dict` directly into `create_engine()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992181/6560549

Comment: use `url = URL.create(**config)` to avoid deprecation error

Comment: I think that the all-caps "URL" in the last line should be lowercase "url".